# Done button click of UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uidocumentinteraction

Hello All
I did search for this, but didn't get anything useful.
 I need to get "`Done`" button click action of `UIDocumentInteractionController`. Can anyone please guide me? I am making an app for iPhone & iPad both.

**Update**:- I also need to hide "`Share`" button at top right corner. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine whether a user has selected "Done" via the UIDocumentInteractionController's delegate. Simply:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
...
@end

...

UIDocumentInteractionController* controller = ...;
controller.delegate = self;

...

- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"User has dismissed preview");
}
```

As for removing "Share", this isn't easy, and Apple suggest you should have it in all cases. This makes sense, if you're previewing a PDF, the user may very well wish to view it in a dedicated PDF reader, or to email it. If you don't want the ability to share due to business/security reasons, then you'll need to try and render the document yourself. How this is done depends on the document,

Comment: What I want is only to preview the document(any type i.e image, pdf, etc) and don't want user to share it. So, need to hide this "Share" button.

Comment: You could try rendering it within a UIWebView, this way you have a bit more control.

Comment: @WDUK, is it possible to get Share button click action on document preview , I have to track user clicked action on share button .

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.2

You can add this delegate method for performing operations on the click of done button in UIDocumentInteractionController.

```
func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
    print("Done Button called here")
}
```